# Select data from multiple date columns with and conditions in Code Igniter

Tags: php, mysql

i want to get data from database with multiple AND conditions on multiple datetime columns.
for example

```
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('BaseTbl');
   $this->db->where('remarkDate<=',date('Y-m-d') );
   $this->db->where('createdDate!=',date('Y-m-d') );
   $query = $this->db->get();
   $result = $query->num_rows();      
   return $result;
```

but its not fetching correct result. please help.

Comment: do you have sample data?

Comment: its returning whole data of table. @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ

Comment: Can you please provide us the sample data and the result you want from the query. The data you gave is not sufficient here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('BaseTbl');
   $this->db->where('date(remarkDate) <=',date('Y-m-d') );
   $this->db->where('date(createdDate) !=',date('Y-m-d') );
   $query = $this->db->get();
   $result = $query->num_rows();      
   return $result;
```

Hope this will work

Answer (score -1):

You can try this by putting a space after remarkDate and createdDate, it should work.

### EX::

$this->db->where('remarkDate <=',date('Y-m-d') );
$this->db->where('createdDate !=',date('Y-m-d') );

Comment: yes i tried but not working. it not returning result if both conditions is true. @Muhibbullah Ansary